# Not sure how to build this bell-curve chart

Tags: c#, .net, mschart, charts

Here is problem I'm trying to solve. It's for logistics company. I got all other inputs/variations taken care of so I have 1 straight-forward thing to do.

There is table with historical orders and prices paid per/mile. I need to present/visualize pricing distribution. Let's say prices vary from 0.80 to 1.80 per mile. Most loads done at around 1.40 per mile.

There is no special requirement HOW I should visualize that but the way I see it - 
X axis will show price
Y axis will show loads count
I will show it as a curved line.

To make it look nice - I probably need to aggregate gata into 5c buckets so I don't have many points on X axis.

Does it sound right? I don't want' to reinvent wheel and maybe there is built-in function to take care of all that in 4.0 chart control?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSCharting samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) has a "HistogramChartHelper" utility class that can make histograms easier.
I copied and made some minor edits to use in my project.

Comment: Bingo. Thats a keyword I was looking for. I'm already looking at their samples, I didn't know what the proper term. Let's see what this class does - maybe it's better to do it on database side so I don't bring too much data

Answer (score 1):

Your methodology sounds good to me. Aggregating things into buckets can definitely help to drive the point home ... just don't hesitate to play with the bucket sizes as an arbitrary 5c might not be the "right" size. I would also recommend giving the old bar charts a try ... depending on how many data points you have, I find it sometimes just looks better as a series of bar charts :-)

Comment: I am using Microsoft Chart. I guess I was curious if it's got built-in "buckets" feature. Because this problem sounds very "common" I was wondering if I really need to DO this.

Comment: I've never come across it myself if it does exist :-) the API basically just lets you add new data points to a series as necessary. You would have to write in the grouping logic yourself.